# Внешние ключи в форме

Tags: python, django

Не могу никак сгенерить форму для модели

модель

```
class Reviews(models.Model):
user=models.ForeignKey(User)
good=models.ForeignKey(Good)
description=models.TextField(blank=True, verbose_name=u'Общее впечатление')
negative=models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, verbose_name=u'Недостатки')
positive=models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, verbose_name=u'Достоинства')
quantity_star=models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
review_score=models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
date_last_change=models.DateField(auto_now=True)
date_create=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

форма

```
class ReviewsForm(forms.ModelForm):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    user=kwargs.pop('user', None)
    good=kwargs.pop('good', None)
    super(ReviewsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['user']= forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=UserReg.objects.get(user=user))
    self.fields['good'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Good.objects.get(id=good))


class Meta:
    model=Reviews
    fields=('positive', 'negative', 'description',)
    widgets={
        'positive':forms.TextInput(attrs={'id':'positive'}),
        'negative': forms.TextInput(attrs={'id': 'negative'}),
        'description': forms.TextInput(attrs={'id': 'description'}),
    }
```

Проблем в том, что при таком определении формы, в форме пропадают все поля
Нужно сделать форму в которую 3 указанных поля в 'fields' будут заполняться пользователем, а поля с внешними ключами будут заполняться во фьюшке.

Еще такой вариант нашел, но тоже не работает, никак не могу заставить работать.
В этом варианте все поля, но при сохранении пишет, что не валидно поле с картинкой, при этом при сохранении в админке все сохраняется нормально, что я упустил?

```
class UserCreateForms(UserCreationForm):
error_messages = {'password_mismatch': "The two password fields didn't match."}
first_name = forms.CharField(label='First Name', max_length=30)
last_name = forms.CharField(label='Last Name', max_length=30)
password1=forms.CharField(max_length=30, widget=forms.PasswordInput)
password2 = forms.CharField(max_length=30, widget=forms.PasswordInput)
email = forms.EmailField()

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ("username", "first_name", "last_name", "email",)


class UserProfil(forms.ModelForm):

avatar = forms.ImageField(
    widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'class': 'ask-signup-avatar-input',}),
    required=False, label=u'Аватар'
)
def clean_avatar(self):
    avatar = self.cleaned_data.get('avatar')
    print('avatar', avatar)
    if avatar is None:
        raise forms.ValidationError('None Image')
    if 'image' not in avatar.content_type:
        raise forms.ValidationError('Not Image')
    return avatar


class Meta:
     model = UserReg
     fields = ('avatar', )
```

фрагмент views.py

```
 form=ReviewsForm(request.POST, user=request.user, good=Good.objects.get(id=id_good)) 
 form.save()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

может поможет кому, т.е. было необходимо объявить передаваемые аргументы в конструкторе...

```
class ReviewsForm(forms.ModelForm):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.user = kwargs.pop("user", None)
    self.good = kwargs.pop("good", None)
    super(ReviewsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    inst = super(ReviewsForm, self).save(commit=False)
    inst.good = self.good
    inst.user = self.user
    inst.save()
    return inst


class Meta:
    model=Reviews
    fields=('positive', 'negative', 'description',)
    widgets={
        'positive':forms.TextInput(attrs={'id':'positive'}),
        'negative': forms.TextInput(attrs={'id': 'negative'}),
        'description': forms.TextInput(attrs={'id': 'description'}),
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Создайте новую форму только с теми полями, которые вам нужны. Настроить отображаемые поля можно атрибутом класса Meta [fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#django.forms.ModelForm)

Те поля, которые не должны заполняться пользователем, заполняйте при вызове метода [save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) (этот метод есть только в ModelForm). Пример можно посмотреть [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3929671/3049150)

UPD: попробуйте так

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    good = kwargs.pop('good', None)
    user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
    inst = super(ReviewsForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)  # Вместо ReviewsForm подставить название класса
    inst.good = good
    inst.user = user
    inst.save()
    return inst
```

Comment: Спасибо, я понял, что нужно переопределить метод save,но не могу понять как написать так что бы можно было передавать дополнительные аргументы (экземпляры внешних ключей) в фьюшке во время обработки формы

Comment: пытаюсь делать так           [ 'def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        inst = super(Reviews, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        good=kwargs.pop('good', None)
        user=kwargs.pop('user', None)
        inst.good=good
        inst.user=user
        inst.save()
        return inst']

Comment: @user208820 добавил пример, у вас super неправильный

Comment: ошибка __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user'...не знает, нужно в конструкторе я так понимаю объявить args и kwargs??? Во фьшке так передаю аргументы  form=ReviewsForm(request.POST, user=request.user, good=Good.objects.get(id=id_good))     form.save()

Comment: Нет, args и kwargs - это параметры, которые передаются в функцию. Значит надо pop перенести раньше этого вызова

Comment: не понял, куда перенести pop??? pop же итак находится в начале метода save???

Comment: Исправил пример

Comment: не помогло, я пробовал так...